# Lista suspensa com critério de repetição

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Tenho um lista de conferencia, onde na Plan1, coluna A', será digitado apenas os cods que estiverem na Plan2, coluna A' mais com um critério so pode se repetir o total de vezes que estiver na plan2.

- 1. Para digitar na Plan1, apenas os cods da Plan2 eu utilizei uma Validação de Dados (desativando a lista suspensa) quando digitado um cod que não esta na plan2 retorna uma msg de erro. até ae Ok.

Meu problema é que na Plan1, posso repetir infinitamente se passar pelo critério da lista, preciso que os cods da Plan1, se repitam apenas as vezes que estiver na plan2, coluna B'.

Plan1: 
Coluna A: Entrada de cod (se repetem, por 'X' Vezes)

Plan2:
Coluna A: Cod (nao se repetem)
Coluna B: Qtd (total de vezes que o cod, pode se repetir na Plan1)

Imagem:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/UtVN2.png

Answer (score 1):

Vamos alterar a fonte para sua validação. Na Plan2, na coluna C, você vai incluir um "saldo", que fará a diferença entre o limite máximo na coluna B e a contagem de ocorrências já inseridas. Por exemplo, inclua esta fórmula na Plan2!C3 e seguintes:

```
=$B3-CONT.SE(Plan1.$A$3:$A$1000;$A3)
```

Na Plan2!D3 em diante, você inclui

```
=SE($C3>0;$A3;"")
```

Dessa forma, a coluna D terá os mesmos códigos da coluna A, porém substituindo por vazio aqueles que já alcançaram seu limite. Então você muda a validação na Plan1, para usar a Plan2!D como lista de validação.